# SignalR Hub not receiving user from client WPF (.netcore 3.1)

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, .net-core-3.1

I have a WPF client which connects successfully to a Hub, but I cannot pass the user of the client to the Hub.

My `connection.User?.Identity?.Name` in my class implementing from `IUserIdProvider` returns **null**.

For my WPF client I use this to connect against the Hub:

```
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(viewModel.Endpoint, opts =>
    {
        opts.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
        opts.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    })
    .Build();
```

I have then the following provider registered as singleton:

```
    public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
        {
            return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned above, the `connection.User?.Identity?.Name;` is returning null.

I don't know what else I can do to pass the user name from my client (WPF) to my Hub.

By the way, my `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();

        services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
        {
            hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });

        services.AddScoped<IBuildsService, BuildsService>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<SyncCodeHub>("/signalr");
        });
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I update the code with:

`services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

But the problem continues, the identity user (IUserIdProvider) is returning null when called from the WPF client. I'm running the API locally with IISExpress.

**EDIT:**

From Microsoft docs:

> Windows Authentication is only supported by the browser client when using Microsoft Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge.

So I'm wondering if this is even possible with an Desktop as a client. I assume it should work, so I'm wondering if I'm still missing a point or if this is a bug related to the Version of SignalR I#m using (3.1.3)

Comment: Are you trying to use Windows authentication? Then you need to [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) your ASP.NET Core app accordingly.

Comment: @mm8 this didn't help unfortunately. And yes, I use Windows Authentication.

Comment: @mm8 can you post an answer? This was indeed a configuration missing in the `launchSettings.json` as per doc. I have better described it in here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) your ASP.NET Core app to use Windows authentication by calling `AddAuthentication` in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

You should also edit your `launchSettings.json` file according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio):

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52171/",
        "sslPort": 44308
    }
}
```

Comment: New to .net and it took me ages, thank you.